# Is it possible to set the version number of SharePoint document?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, versioning, version-history

I have two site collections in SharePoint Online.  One is the live site collection and one is the Testing Site.

I want to upload a document onto the Test Site Collection, make some changes to it and then copy the document to the live site collection setting the version number to be the version number of the document on the Testing Site.

Answer (score 5):

**No,** it's not possible to set the document version number manually in **all** SharePoint versions,

**As a workaround solution**

- In case the current document version number in the test site is **higher** than document version number in the live site.

  - Perform multiple check out and check in to reach the desired version number

[image]

- In case the current document version number in the test site is **lower** than document version number in the live site.

  - Try to delete the higher versions until reach to the desired version-1 then upload your document.

[image]